# js obj -> json file (ajax, php)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I currently am getting a 200 green response, however my data is still NOT being written to my json file (i.e. it is still blank)

The JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('form#saveTemp').submit(function() {
        let savdAta = JSON.stringify($('form#saveTemp').serializeObject());
        //let tempName = savdAta.styleName;
        console.log(savdAta);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify($('form#saveTemp').serializeObject()));

        $.ajax({
          url: './php/data.php',
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: "application/json",  
          data: {
              template: savdAta
          },
          success: function(msg) {
              console.log('data sent to php file, but..');
          }               
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

data in console from `savdAta` is in below format: *i.e.*

```
{"styleName":"","fillType":"none","fillTrans":"0"}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!isset($_POST['savdAta']) && !empty($_POST['savdAta'])) {
    $savdAta = $_POST['savdAta'];

    $jsonObject = json_encode($savdAta);
    file_put_contents('./data.json', $jsonObject);
}
```

Update: Now I have the below, with no errors, and yet still my .json file is blank:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['template'])) {
    $savdAta = $_POST['template'];

    file_put_contents('./data.json', $savdAta);
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `contentType: "application/json",`. `$_POST['savdAta']` is JSON, but the top-level POST data is not.

Comment: Silly mistake: `if (!isset($_POST['savdAta'])`. You can just delete that condition anyway, because `empty` checks for `isset`.

Comment: the variable name `savdAta` isn't sent to PHP - so you won't see it as a POST variable - once you fix the contentType, you're probably sending the data in `template` POST variable - because that's what you've written in the code

Comment: Your code does literally nothing and returns a `200` if that `if` condition isn't true. You might want to tack on a couple more lines of code to indicate error conditions.

Comment: Thanks; however even with all the suggestions: my data, i.e. {"styleName":"","fillType":"none","fillTrans":"0"}
 will not write to the json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST variable is `template` and you're only executing if NOT set AND NOT empty, which is not what you want and would never evaluate to `true` anyway:

```
//Not needed
//header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!empty($_POST['template'])) {
    $savdAta = $_POST['template'];

    //This is already JSON
    //$jsonObject = json_encode($savdAta);
    file_put_contents('./data.json', $savdAta);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, even with this, the json file is completely blank.....

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to the top of file to see errors.